# Determine Point Coordinates In 3D

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, euclidean-distance

I have a line that exists in 3D that is between two known points: {X1, Y1, Z1} and {X2, Y2, Z2}.

```
(X1,Y1,X1)----------(X2,Y2,Z2)
```

There is a point (Xd,Yd,Zd) on the line between those points at distance D from (X1,Y1,Z1).

```
(X1,Y1,X1)---D---(Xd,Yd,Zd)-----(X2,Y2,Z2)
```

How can I determine the coordinates of point (Xd,Yd,Zd)?

Comment: Huh? I can't understand your question at all.

Comment: Me neither, it all gets blurry after the D part

Comment: I think he means to move D distance from point 1 toward point 2.

Comment: use the parametric form of a line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to move the distance D from point 1 to point 2 :

```
P1 = [ X1, Y1, Z1 ]
P2 = [ X2, Y2, Z2 ]
```

The line vector can be described as :

```
V = P2 - P1 = [ Xv = X2 - X1, Yv = Y2 - Y1, Zv = Z2 - Z1 ]
```

The line's length can be determined as :

```
VL = SQRT(Xv^2 + Yv^2 + Zv^2)     // ^2 = squared
```

The line's versor aka the unit vector can be determined as :

```
v = V / VL = [Xv / VL, Yv / VL, Zv / VL]
```

The target point PD can be determined as :

```
Pd = P1 + D * v // Starting from P1 advance D times v
```

Please note that P1 and v are vectors and D is a scalar

Answer (score 1):

First, determine the length of the line segment:

```
d=sqrt((X1-X2)^2+(Y1-Y2)^2+(Z1-Z2)^2))
```

You are moving D from P1=(X1,Y1,Z1) toward P2=(X2,Y2,Z2).  This puts you at the point (X3,Y3,Z3):

```
{XYZ}3={XYZ}1+(D/d)*({XYZ}2-{XYZ}1})
```

Where you expand that into 3 equations, one for each of X, Y, and Z.

This works because you are D/d of the way between P1 and P2.  Check: Say D=d.  Then you should be at exactly P2.

Answer (score 0):

Take the vector between the two points

```
<X2-X1, Y2-Y1, Z2-Z1>
```

Turn that into a unit vector pointing in the same direction but with length 1. You do that by dividing by the distance between the two points:

```
         <X2-X1, Y2-Y1, Z2-Z1>
---------------------------------------
sqrt((X2-X1)^2 + (Y2-Y1)^2 + (Z2-Z1)^2)
```

Then multiply that by D and add to your original point to get the new point.

```
                            <X2-X1, Y2-Y1, Z2-Z1>
(X1, Y1, Z1) + D * ---------------------------------------
                   sqrt((X2-X1)^2 + (Y2-Y1)^2 + (Z2-Z1)^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear combination problem:

dist = distance(p1, p2)

distance D is given

f = D / dist (fractional coordinate of point D within LineSeg (p1, p2)

pD = LinearCombo (1-f, p1, f, p2)  (coordinates of point distance D from p1)